# IronPython: import random fails in IronPython Interactive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, ironpython

This fails in **IronPython Interactive** inside Visual Studio 2010:

```
» import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named random
```

The same works fine in IronPython code in Visual Studio. It also works fine if I launch `ipy.exe` inside a Windows command prompt. What is the problem with IronPython Interactive and import? How do I fix Python Interactive so that it can import Python modules?

sys.path in IronPython Interactive gives this:

```
» import sys
» sys.path
['.',
 'C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 10.0\\COMMON7\\IDE\\EXTENSIONS\\MICROSOFT\\IRONSTUDIO\\0.4\\Lib',
 'C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 10.0\\COMMON7\\IDE\\EXTENSIONS\\MICROSOFT\\IRONSTUDIO\\0.4\\DLLs']
```

sys.path in ipy.exe on Windows command prompt gives this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['.',
 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I am using IronPython 2.7, Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see `sys.path` directories are different;
I suspect `random` module is implemented in `IronPython.Modules.dll`, then you should check if such dll is present in the paths of IronPython interactive.

If it's present, the problem is another and I don't know what could be...

otherwise in Ironpython interactive, before `import random` do:

```
sys.path.append(path)
```

with `path` being the folder of `IronPython.Modules.dll` (I guess 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7') and it should work.

Comment: Is there a way to save the path such that it is already appended whenever I open IronPython Interactive?

Comment: @Ashwin: Unfortunately, I don't know, sorry... Anyway, I've noticed that you already found a bug-report like yours [(here)](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/29077), I'll follow it :)

Comment: Thank you, but in my situation I have to use the `Lib` sub-directory instead of the one containing IronPython.Modules.dll. fyi: I'm using IronPython 2.6